# How to set the member values inside of a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Is there a way to set the value of members of an array with foreach?

```
<?
  $arr = array(0=>'a',1=>'b',2=>'c',3=>'d');

  foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $value = 'a';
  }

  var_dump($arr);
?>
```

returns:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "d"
}
```

Where what I am trying to get it to return is:

```
   array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "a"
    }
```

Here is a link to the codepad I was using.

http://codepad.org/FQpPYFtz

Comment: +1 for providing a complete, minimal and usefully abstracted sample. More people should do it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = array(0=>'a',1=>'b',2=>'c',3=>'d');

foreach($arr as $key => &$value) {  // <-- use reference to $value
  $value = 'a';
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Exactly the quick fix I was searching for. Looks like I am going to have to try harder to understand this reference thing. Thank you for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score 3):

It is quite simple:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = 'new value';
}
```